# Which test to use in "Ordinal x Categorical" Data

Tags: r, biostatistics

I would like to ask a very fundamental question. First of all, I will simplify it to tell you the problem easily. Can I classify patients' ages into age groups (like <25, 25-35, 35-45, +45) and then put them into a statistical difference test according to an exposure (like radiation). I know I can test it by T-test because they are numeric variables in the beginning; however, does this increase the significance? If not, do I still need it? (T-test is already significant by the way.)

Now I will tell you the real problem. In all textbooks in my profession, this biomarker is investigated according to some thresholds as you can see below. But when it comes to academic setting, we always test them with t-test. I would like to investigate this levels according to their ordinal places within these subgroups. So, is there a way to do this, and is this a good way to analyse this data?

Thank you in advance!

Sincerely.

| Serum X Levels - Subgrouped | Control | Exposure | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Low | a | b | (a+b) |
| Suboptimal | x | y | (x+y) |
| Normal | c | z | (c+z) |
| High | k | l | (k+l) |

*all variables you see are the counts within the groups.

Comment: Why bin the serum level at all?

Comment: Sorry @Dave, cannot catch you. What do you mean by "bin"? Did you want to say that why I subgrouped them?

Comment: Exactly. Why group them in bins like that when you get numerical measurements?

Comment: Yes, actually I asked the same question to myself. I just wondered is there a practice like this or any logic behind. Because I lose the advantages of a continuous variable to bin them into groups, and only get a little advantage of a ordinary categorical variable, which doesn't contribute much in this circumstance.